# Cast DateTIme without affecting timezone in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Tried to cast the datatime object ,which is queried from database. Value is in UTC time.
is it affect the local timezone when i tried to cast the object ?

**var daytime = (DateTime)reader["day"];**

reader["day"] is a object and value is in UTC time. For accessing the value i changed it into DateTime. my intention is i want to convert this value to epoch time.

```
var daytime = (DateTime)reader["day"];
long epochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
long unixTime = ((daytime.Ticks - epochTicks) / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
```

Comment: If you can you should store a datetimeoffset in the database. Otherwise if you know it to always be UTC, you can change the DateTimeKind after you cast it.

Comment: @Sinatr i don't want to convert the data. Just cast the data. receiving data in object type.In the example it  convert/parse into Datetime?. this is not correct for  my case.am i right ?

Comment: The short answer to your question is *no*.  Neither casting from `object` to `DateTime` nor subtracting ticks would be affected by time zone.  The code you wrote will work fine.  However, you could do this instead: `long unixTime = new DateTimeOffset(daytime, TimeSpan.Zero).ToUnixTimeSeconds();`